# Only one process is passing through my mutex lock and the others are hanging

Tags: c, process, mutex, semaphore

So I am working on a program that will allow me to open single instances of files using multiple processes without deadlock occurring. So the key function to my program is below. It basically decides if a program can execute a file based on an adjacency graph. So that part all seems to work fine.

The trouble I am running into seems to be with my mutex locking. So basically how the program executes is it decides that one process will need to run completely before other processes will be able to open files without deadlock (this is fine and expected behavior). But once that first process finishes it just hangs and I believe that I have narrowed it down to my pthread_mutex_lock call at the top part of the code. Yet as you can see I unlock it so I am quite confused.

Could it have something to do with the fact that my mutex is being used in the shared memory block? I can't imagine that it would cause problems and there is no other way for me to do it really. Also I tried the same thing using a semaphore with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
FILE *openFile(char *path, char *mode) {

int segId = shmget(systemKey, size, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | IPC_CREAT);
memStruct* ourMem = (memStruct*)shmat(segId, NULL, 0);

pthread_mutex_lock(&ourMem->openMutex);//~~~~~~~~~~

int hasCycle = containsCycle(ourMem, path);


if(hasCycle == 0) {
    FILE* fileToReturn = fopen(path, mode);
    int positionOfFile = getFilePosition(path, ourMem);
    int positionOfProcess = getProcessPosition(getpid(), ourMem);

    ourMem->adjMatrix[positionOfFile][positionOfProcess] = 2;
    ourMem->Available[positionOfFile] = 0;
    ourMem->fileArray[positionOfFile] = fileToReturn;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ourMem->openMutex);//~~~~~~~~~~

    return fileToReturn;
}
else {
    while(1) {
        hasCycle = containsCycle(ourMem, path);

            if(hasCycle == 0) {
                    FILE* fileToReturn = fopen(path, mode);
                    int positionOfFile = getFilePosition(path, ourMem);
                    int positionOfProcess = getProcessPosition(getpid(), ourMem);

                    ourMem->adjMatrix[positionOfFile][positionOfProcess] = 2;
                    ourMem->Available[positionOfFile] = 0;
                    ourMem->fileArray[positionOfFile] = fileToReturn;

                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ourMem->openMutex);//~~~~~~~~~~

                    return fileToReturn;
        }
    }
}



pthread_mutex_unlock(&ourMem->openMutex);//~~~~~~~~~~


return NULL;
}
```

Comment: >> "But once that first process finishes it just hangs " - Are  you stuck in `while` loop?

Comment: @Prabhu That was my first thought too but I am not. I have tried printing out and my processes make it to the point right before the mutex lock but never after it (except my first process)

Comment: Sharing a pthread mutex across processes seems like a bad idea. A pthread mutex is designed to work with threads created by `pthread_create`. For inter-process control use an inter-process semaphore, e.g. from `semget`.

Comment: @user3386109 I did it all using a semaphore before trying out mutex because I was hoping that would be the problem but it acted in the same way. :(

Comment: I am doubtful of the wisdom of using a pthread mutex for general IPC, but you should at least be sure to *initialize it* with `pthread_mutex_init()` before using it.  Does that happen somewhere else?

Comment: Semaphores can be a little harder to use. You'll need to put together an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with semaphores and then ask a question here if you can't get it to work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I definitely initialized it. Maybe I need to use a semaphore with sem_open instead of sem_init? My semaphore is stored in a shared memory block so I don't see how it would matter but I am out of ideas...

Comment: There are two completely separate semaphore implementations: the UNIX system V flavor, and the POSIX flavor.  They do not mix.  You should use the POSIX flavor (placed in a POSIX shared memory segment and initialized via `sem_init()`) unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah I am using the POSIX implementation. Basically what it comes down to is if I get rid of the semaphore it doesn't run correctly because I need a semaphore but if I put in a semaphore it never finishes. Ugh.

Comment: It looks like you are using the System V flavor of shared memory.  There, too, I would recommend the POSIX flavor instead.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah I thought I was using POSIX shared memory. The type I am using is what my professor showed us (we need to be able to use a key to get the memory block) so if POSIX has that I will switch.

Comment: As @user3386109 suggested, however, put together a semaphore-based MCVE.

Comment: No, `shmget()` is the SysV flavor.  The POSIX flavor involves `shm_open()`.  In truth, however, you should be able to put your semaphore in either kind.

Comment: By the way, be sure to initialize your semaphore for use between separate processes.  The second argument to `sem_init()` must be `1` for that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Aaaaand that solved my problem. Literally hours of debugging and I just didn't set it to a 1 instead of 0....

Comment: use a 'named semaphore' or a 'named mutex'.  either one results in a globally visible object that is buried somewhere in the OS file system.  Have each process init the named object (after the first init, following init calls will have no effect.    do not use 'pthread*()'  because the code is working with separate processes, not separate threads.

Comment: @JohnBollinger,  yes, that brings back frustrating memory’s from before I knew to use an initial value of 1 for inter-process semaphores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that with sem_init(&semName, 1, 1) I had a 0 as the second argument which was blocking interprocess communication.